# Executar algo depois de uma animação - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Eu tenho a seguinte animação quando inicializo meu projeto:

```
    public ConfigInicial_Empresa()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        brush = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#444");
        window.Background = brush;

        DoubleAnimation fadingAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        fadingAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        fadingAnimation.From = 0;
        fadingAnimation.To = 2;
        fadingAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.75);
        fadingAnimation.AutoReverse = true;

        tbBemVindo.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.OpacityProperty, fadingAnimation);
    }
```

Gostaria de executar alguma coisa logo depois que termina essa animação...

Como eu posso obter sucesso pra essa tarefa?

Agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta colocar a assinatura de um Handler no Completed antes de chamar o beginAnimation.

```
 public ConfigInicial_Empresa()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        brush = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#444");
        window.Background = brush;

        DoubleAnimation fadingAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        fadingAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        fadingAnimation.From = 0;
        fadingAnimation.To = 2;
        fadingAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.75);
        fadingAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
        fadingAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(fadingAnimation_Completed);
        tbBemVindo.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.OpacityProperty, fadingAnimation);
    }

private void fadingAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //NXZERO > METALLICA
}
```

Fonte -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Eu tinha tentado dessa forma, coloquei a fadingAnimation.Completed em baixo da tbBemVindo.BeginAnimation e não funcionou... Porque sera?

Comment: Simples, você deu START na animação. Ela acabou. e só depois você falou para depois que ela acabar (ELA JA ACABOU) você quer que uma ação aconteça... dai não funciona... essa regra vale para outras coisas na programação.

Comment: Faz sentido... Obrigado :D